# Not sure of slow cooker setting in my multi pot

Tags: slow-cooking

I have a Cook's Essentials K22739 multi use pot.  It has 2 pressure cooker settings,  and one setting each for steam, brown, warm and slow cook.  If I have a small pork roast whose packaging says to slow cook with one inch of water on high for 4 hours or with one inch of water for 4 hours in a pre-heated 350 degree oven, how long should I slow cook it in my pot which has only one setting for slow cook???

Answer (score 1):

I found the [manual](https://www.qvc.com/cd/pdf/K22739-PressureCookerManual.pdf) (PDF) for it on the QVC website. Reading that - which is frustrating because it's in a strange order - if you find what's labeled as page 8, it says that the cooker runs at 180 F, which is the equivalent of the low setting on a traditional slow cooker:

> 5. [. . .] The longest cooking time is 9 1/2 hours with a temperature of 180°F. Note: 180°F is the lowest setting on a traditional slow cooker.

The [Crock Pot website](https://www.crock-pot.com/service-and-support/product-support/product-faqs/help-and-how-to-use/cook-time-and-quantity/help-and-how-to-use-cook-time-and-quantity-faq.html) suggests that the equivalent of four hours on high is eight hours on low. Which seems to be supported on other sources, too.

So...

#### With your multi-cooker, you'll want to cook your roast for about 8 hours on the slow cook setting.